# Why did Nano just mangle my code?

Tags: c, arm, virtual-machine, buffer-overflow, nano

Using VM VirtualBox I'm running a copy of 32bit Linux which is itself running a VM for an ARM environment. This entire setup is needed to have an environment that lets me do buffer overflows for a class.

Twice now, I've come back to my code in Nano to find that the entire file had just been changed to a line of nothing but.

```
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
```

going on and on. The first time it happened I thought I made some kind of mistake overwriting my C file with my compiled code. I moved on and worked on a different machine but now it's happened a second time and I'm sure I didn't accidentally overwrite anything.

Does anyone have any idea what could possibly cause this? Is there anyway to save my code?

Comment: have you check your character encoding is consistent between editors? or the line separator?

Comment: If I open the file in another editor like VIM it comes up very similar. I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Comment: Despite your assertion that you didn't overwrite anything, you clearly overwrote it.  Type `file a.out` or whatever your executable name is to see what it is.  Type `hexdump -C a.out` to see what bytes it contains.

Comment: `^@` would be byte 0, so your file got filled with zeros. This is definitely not normal. You could try some other editor than *nano* and see if it keeps happening... If it keeps happening, then you have something which is corrupting your files. Or then you just have some strange command in some script or makefile, which you should not have.

Comment: Is your ARM "VM" by any chance user-mode QEMU (i.e. not isolated full-system emulation)? The combination of "intentionally overflowing buffers to smash random memory" and "seeing weird corruption" seems _not entirely unrelated_.

Comment: It is QEMU, I should have mentioned that.